# Can emergency contact number be modified

Tags: ios

I know iPhone has a "emergency" option before the phone is unlocked that can call 911 only. could that be modified given the reason is for emergency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API to change this number. Maybe you would be able to change it on Jailbroken device, but there is no official way to do this.

Anyway is there any good reason to change the emergency number ?